# Parameters in Visual Studio c++ 2010

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I just installed Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express (BTW. great ide). I have to make simple application, but I will open it from command prompt, and I need using parameters. So my question is: how to using parameters in Visual C++ .NET 2010 Express? I need one string and some int. It's special creator to do this or I must change code (if yes - how?)?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To debug your program with command line arguments, use Project + Properties, Debugging, Command Arguments setting.

Click around some more to get familiar with what's there, you'll need it sooner or later.  Press F1 if things sound mysterious.

Comment: I add 'adres' in this input, but I don't see it in  code. How to use this var?

Comment: Check your favorite C or C++ programming book to learn how to use the argc and argv arguments passed to main().

Comment: You do realize that this is not C++ code?  Find the Main() method for a C++/CLI program in the .cpp file of your project.  Its *args* argument is a string array of the command line arguments.  I recommend a new question, properly tagged as [c++-cli] if you need more help.

Comment: Also note that a GUI app like this rarely uses command line arguments.  Maybe you just used the wrong project template.  Use Win32 + Console Application to get the traditional one.